# Scanner scans first line and only the first input of the second line

Tags: java

I'm creating this code where a scanner should scan every word in the text file and then proceed to save each and every one of them in a specific array. But every time the scanner starts to scan it only reaches the next line and stops at the first word. I don't know what is causing this exactly. I'm using a delimiter where it separates words between commas ",".

Here is the piece of code:

```
package ex13a;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Work
 */
public class Ex13a {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static int[] number = new int[100];
static String[] f_users = new String[100];
static String[] l_users = new String[100];
static String[] passwd = new String[100];
static int i = 0;
static String fullName;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String path = "C:\\Users\\Work\\Desktop\\users.txt";
File inFile = new File(path);
Scanner inPut = new Scanner(inFile).useDelimiter(",");
Scanner inPut2 = new Scanner(inFile);
while(inPut.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(number[i] = inPut.nextInt());
    System.out.println(f_users[i] = inPut.next());
    System.out.println(l_users[i] = inPut.next());
    System.out.println(passwd[i] = inPut.next());

    i++;

}
```

It throws me that error:

```
1
Ahmed
Dhaif
asdf56
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
2
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at ex13a.Ex13a.main(Ex13a.java:32)
C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:     Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Read the file line by line using `nextLine()`, then parse the line using `.split(",")`. Also, JavaScript and Java are two completely separate, unrelated languages, and your question has nothing to do with Netbeans. Remove the javascript and netbeans tags.

Comment: It is kind of weird that it printed the value `2`, presumably from the `nextInt()` call for the second line in the text file, but it fails in a call to `nextInt()`. However, if it printed the value returned by `nextInt()`, it would be on the next statement, which is a call to `next()`, not `nextInt()`. Are you *sure* this is the code you're running?

Comment: Read the error messages, they're there to help you. To help people answer, it would help if you provided your input data too.

Answer (score 1):

Grab line by line, then split the lines around the comma, then parse the strings returned.

```
Scanner inPut = new Scanner(inFile);
while(inPut.hasNextLine()){
    String [] data = inPut.nextLine().split(",");
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
    number[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[0]); //to add to your arrays
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
    i++;
}
```

Note you should check that the array is the correct size and the string is actually an Integer. You should be able to do that. But this should get you started.

If you are going to store the values in a data structure, use something dynamic and not a data structure of fixed length like an array.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message. The exception was raised in the `nextInt()` method. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), for `nextInt()`

```
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer
regular expression, or is out of range
```

So the token you're reading isn't what you think it is. You could replace the `nextInt()` call with something else to see what it is, and go from there.

For the record, this code is remarkably trusting

1. The loop checks for "is there any token", and then assumes it is an
   integer.
2. You assume that if there is 1 token, there will be 3 more after that each loop iteration.
3. There is no protection for the number of entries, you assume it will be <=100

**Edit**

My guess is there is something about the end-of-line that isn't printable, so when you read it it looks like an integer, but actually is something like ^r###, where "^r" is a control code and ### are digits.

I bet if you change the `hasNext()` to `hasNextInt()` it will just stop after processing 1 line. Read the file with a binary editor to see what you're really reading.

Comment: It is a trusting code since I already have the knowledge of its content and how its gonna change in the future. I replaced nextInt with next to see if its an int or not. Surprisingly it shows the whole file but displaying this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException    at the middle followed with other errors.

Comment: by the way the next expected number was an int.

Comment: @M.J - Without seeing the input data (input data would have been useful anyway, as I commented above), and the results of your test I can only guess what your next problem is, but it sounds like it might be an end-of-file boundary condition. Hmm, actually it sounds like an end-of-line problem, and something non-printable, or part of your end of line is not being recognized as whitespace. Try reading the first couple of lines of the file character by character, and outputting the character code - or edit the file in a binary editor - to look for end-of-line strangeness.